# Does containerd provide any way to pause containers like in Docker?

Tags: docker, containerd

Docker provides [this](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/container_pause/) mechanism to pause the container.

Is there an equivalent in `containerd` or will I have to find another way to 'freeze' the container?

The goal is to have a consistent backup - I am looking for another solution than using `fsfreeze`.

Answer (score 0):

Containerd has its own cli called `ctr`

It doesn't seems that `ctr` supports pausing the container.

This is what is currently seems supported:

```
$ ctr container
NAME:
   ctr containers - manage containers

USAGE:
   ctr containers command [command options] [arguments...]

COMMANDS:
     create           create container
     delete, del, rm  delete one or more existing containers
     info             get info about a container
     list, ls         list containers
     label            set and clear labels for a container

OPTIONS:
   --help, -h  show help
```

If it is possible for you to use docker cli the use `docker pause` to pause the container.

If your setup has `runc` available then use [runc pause](https://github.com/opencontainers/runc/blob/master/man/runc-pause.8.md)

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the **containerd client package** ?
If so, there is a method `Pause` and another one `Resume` in the `containerd` package. Those methods allows you to pause/resume a task.

You can find the source code [here](https://github.com/containerd/containerd/blob/master/task.go)

Answer (score 0):

You can use task :

```
ctr task -h
NAME:
   ctr tasks - manage tasks

USAGE:
   ctr tasks command [command options] [arguments...]

COMMANDS:
   attach                   attach to the IO of a running container
   checkpoint               checkpoint a container
   delete, del, remove, rm  delete one or more tasks
   exec                     execute additional processes in an existing container
   list, ls                 list tasks
   kill                     signal a container (default: SIGTERM)
   pause                    pause an existing container
   ps                       list processes for container
   resume                   resume a paused container
   start                    start a container that has been created
   metrics, metric          get a single data point of metrics for a task with the built-in Linux runtime

OPTIONS:
   --help, -h  show help
```